# Qiskit Tutorial on Unitary Operations on a system with 3 stat

Tags: qiskit

In the Qiskit online textbook, when teaching about Unitary Operations on systems having more than 2 states, it then shows the following example:

An example of a unitary operation on a system having three classical states is given by the following 3x3 matrix.
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Assuming that the classical states of the system are 0, 1, and 2, we can describe this operation as addition modulo 3.

$A|0\rangle = |1\rangle$ , $A|1\rangle = |2\rangle$, $A|2\rangle = |0\rangle$

And my question is:
HOW did they get these results from that matrix? 
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that:
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
|0\rangle = \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
|1\rangle = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
|2\rangle = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So by applying simple matrix-multiplications:

$$
A|0\rangle = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix} =
|1\rangle
$$

$$
A|1\rangle = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix} =
|2\rangle
$$

$$
A|2\rangle = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
\end{bmatrix} =
|0\rangle
$$